# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after installing Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have a project made in ASP.NET 4.5 which I run locally with the local IIS Server (Version 10.0.15, the one that comes with Windows 10). I used to work on this project using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and everything was working, I could access and debug the website on http://local.project.com even https worked. After I installed Visual Studio 2017, opened the project (no migration needed) and ran it I started to get the connection reset error: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

In the web.config of my project, I have a rewrite rule to force https, which never caused any problem for me to access locally and when I wanted to debug I just had to comment. Rewrite lines below:

```
<httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="https://project.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
<rewrite>      
  <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectToNonwww" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
      <conditions>           
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?(.*)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{C:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I'm clueless on this issue. I have no idea what VS 2017 changed on my machine that could make this happen. Would you have any tips to help me solve this issue?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 installer does uninstall and reinstall IIS 10 Express, so you might use Jexus Manager to run a quick SSLDiag and see if anything is broken, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it helped me find the solution

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, for some reason when running the project with VS 2017 it messed the configuration of the website bindings. I did this do solve:

1. Right click the website and go to Edit Bindings
2. Edit the binding with SSL
3. Select the certificate and save

Comment: @LexLi I didn't do it via Jexus Manager, I did direct on the IIS

Comment: Yep. Just a reminder that you should make the steps very clear for others to follow.